# How to deal with data visualization tags?

Tags: discussion

Actually, there are two tags for questions that are related (to some extent) to data visualization: [data-visualization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization) (44) and [graphical-techniques](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphical-techniques) (37). What's the difference, if any?

Maybe there are some subtle differences between them that I cannot grasp actually. From what has been posted so far, my understanding is as follows: *data visualization* has to do with "how to display data" (broadly speaking) and "what can I use to display my data" (more of a software issue), whereas *graphical techniques* is perhaps more related to "how may I provide a visual explanation of my data structure".

I am asking that question because I often feel confused when trying to retag some questions.

Any ideas or thoughts on that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there's a distinction it's not clear to me either, so i'd vote to merge them (or make one a synonym for the other, or do a batch rename, or whatever the appropriate terminology / process is).

Comment: Sounds fine to me

Comment: Works for me too.  We can merge them once this question has been accepted.

Comment: Batch rename followed by synonym creation.

Comment: This suggestion looks fine to me too (I also appreciated @Matt's comment).

Comment: I set up the merge operation.  It should be finished at some point later (it must be a batch process).

Comment: I've added the synonyms [graphical-techniques,plot,plotting]->[data-visualization]

Answer (score 6):

I also don't see the distinction in those questions.  `graphical-techniques` just makes me think of [graphical models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graphical_models) (for which we do have a tag), so perhaps removing it and having only `data-visualization` would be best.

The only disadvantage of that is that when people have questions about plots, they're likely to try to tag it by typing "plot" or "graph" and hoping for an auto-complete; `data-visualization` won't be of much use there.  Now, if we could get "plot" and "graph" to autocomplete to `data-visualization`, we'd be set.

Comment: I think tag synonyms will still appear in autocomplete. So if we make graphical-techniques -> data-visualization that should take care of the graph... autocomplete. Perhaps we also need plotting-methods as a synonym for data-visualization.

Comment: Excellent - that's good to know.